# OSX What does "error: cannot convert 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>" mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, homebrew, openmpi, mpic++

I am compiling a friend's code on my machine, and I keep getting hit with this error:

```
 $ mpic++ dummy_file_name.cpp

 dummy_file_name.cpp: In member function 'bool dummy_name1::dummy_name2::python_convert(const StringMultiArray&, PyObject**)':
 dummy_file_name.cpp:430:55:error: cannot convert 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'PyObject* PyString_FromString(const char*)'
     PyList_SetItem(*dst, i, PyString_FromString(src[i]));
```

What does this mean? How can I diagnose or treat this issue? I am using the mpic++ compiler. I have tried googling this error but I have not found any fruitful information.

Here is how I built my environment:

```
brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
export HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-5
export HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-5
brew install openmpi --build-form-source
brew install llvm --with-clang
```

Comment: You probably need `PyList_SetItem(*dst, i, PyString_FromString(src[i].c_str()));`. If that doesn't work, then post what the types of all those variables are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying it can't convert `const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` AKA `const std::string` to `const char*`. This is a proper error for the compiler to report. As stated above you could fix this by using `c_str()`, but that would be an awful hack, and maybe violate some component's open source license.

---

As to why you are getting this error, it may be a mixup with the standard standard c++ libraries. You appear to be using `gcc` for `openmpi` and `llvm` for the link step which is very odd. In addition, you are forcing `c++11` for `gcc`, but not for `llvm`.

Where did you get these build instructions? You may want to lookup an updated set of instructions.

Comment: This did not come with build instructions. I will remove the C++11 build as it seems unnecessary.

Comment: `brew link --force llvm` creates symbolic links to the LLVM binaries in `/usr/local/bin`. It's not a link step as one understands it in programming. (`brew` is a package manager for 3rd party software on OS X)

Comment: @kilojoules, the software you are trying to build seems to be [DAKOTA](https://dakota.sandia.gov/) from Sandia National Laboratories. It actually comes with build instructions and even [ones specifically for OS X](https://dakota.sandia.gov/content/mac-os-x).

Comment: _but that would be an awful hack, and maybe violate some component's open source license._ Could you please explain how adding `.c_str()` may violate the license?

Comment: @Paul It's unclear from context if the `PyString_FromString` call was in his code or in one of the open source libraries he was using. Needless to say, modifying open source code (even if it's just adding `.c_str()`) could be a violation of that library's license.